# Format long text string using css

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have logn string which doesn't fit into table cell. Actually string is a single long word.

Is it possible using css only to wrap such long word?

I have:

```
|klasdflksadjflsadkfj;lasdkfj;lsdkfjldskfjlsadkfj;lsdkfjklsajdf|
```

I want:

```
|klasdflksadjflsadkfj;lasdkfj;lsd|
|kfjldskfjlsadkfj;lsdkfjklsajdf  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need:

```
 word-wrap: break-word
```

in CSS3;

for a cross-browser solution you need to alter the text in the cell (with javascript) and add    some breaks.

Comment: +1 More info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap, https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531186(VS.85,loband).aspx Test: http://jsbin.com/uyuku4

Comment: *"or a cross-browser solution..."* This would appear to be one of those places where the spec is chasing existing practice. The above works in IE6 and up, and current versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari. You may need to use the vendor-specific versions (e.g., `-ms-word-wrap`) if you're in a strict standards mode.

Comment: @T.J Crowder: mind the word *table-cell* in the question... :) http://jsfiddle.net/tDUvf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-wrap:break-word` according to caniuse.com this property has good browser support.